Spring Security || Unit Test with @WithAnonymousUser user keeps getting a 401 response
For an e-commerce project I've secured and unsecured end-points. When testing the endpoints manually in Postman everything works as expected.
The unit test for the secured endpoints give the result I expect, but the test for my unsecured endpoints keep failing by giving a 401 or 403 status. I'm struggling for a while to fix this, but can't figure out how to solve it.
What I did so far

add @PreAuthorize("permitAll()") to the controller
add .with(csrf()) to the mockMvc.perform(post(...
Check security config / changing order, etc.
add and removed @WithAnonymousUser to the unit tests

The endpoints with permitAll should be accessible for everyone. So, a 401 / 403 status should never occur. What I'm I missing?
Controller
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/bookstore")
public class OrderController {
    private final OrderService orderService;
    private final HttpRequestExtractionService extractionService;

    public OrderController(OrderService orderService, HttpRequestExtractionService extractionService) {
        this.orderService = orderService;
        this.extractionService = extractionService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/book/{isbn}/order")
    @PreAuthorize("permitAll()")
    public ResponseEntity<String> orderSingleBook(@PathVariable("isbn") Long isbn, @RequestBody @Valid OrderRequest myOrder) {
        OrderResponse orderResp = OrderMapper
                .fromDtoToResponse(orderService.orderSingleBook(isbn, OrderMapper.fromRequestToDto(myOrder)));
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Your order #" + orderResp.id() + " has been successfully placed.", HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @PostMapping("/basket/order")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('USER')")
    public ResponseEntity<String> orderBasket(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String username = extractionService.extractUserNameFromJwt(request);
        OrderResponse orderResp = OrderMapper.fromDtoToResponse(orderService.orderBasket(username));
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Your order #" + orderResp.id() + " has been successfully placed.", HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

SecurityConfig / securityFilterChain
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/bookstore/basket/order").hasAnyAuthority(USER, ADMIN)
                        .requestMatchers("/api/bookstore/book/{isbn}/order").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/bookstore/user/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/bookstore/basket/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/bookstore/book/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/bookstore/book").hasAuthority(ADMIN)
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/api/bookstore/book/{isbn}").hasAuthority(ADMIN)
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/bookstore/basket/order").hasAnyAuthority(USER, ADMIN)
                        .anyRequest().permitAll()
                )
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService())
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return httpSecurity.build();
    }

The Unit Test
@WebMvcTest(OrderController.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc  //(addFilters = false)
class OrderControllerTest {

    private final String orderSingleBookUri = "/api/bookstore/book/12345/order";
    private final String orderBasketUri = "/api/bookstore/basket/order";
    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;
    @MockBean
    OrderService orderService;
    @MockBean
    HttpRequestExtractionService extractionService;
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String orderConfirm = "Your order #" + 1 + " has been successfully placed.";
    @MockBean
    private JwtService jwtService;
    @MockBean
    private OurUserDetailService ourUserDetailService;

    @BeforeEach
    void init() {
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
    }

    //THIS TEST FAILS 401 / 403
    @Test
    @WithAnonymousUser
    void givenCorrectOrderData_whenPostingANewOrder_thenOrderDtoShouldReturnWithStatus200_andShowOrderNumber() throws Exception {
        //given
        OrderRequest orderRequest = OrderRequestFactory.anOrderDtoBuilder().build();
        OrderDto orderDto = OrderDtoFactory.newOrderDto().build();

        //when
        when(orderService.orderSingleBook(orderRequest.isbn(), OrderMapper.fromRequestToDto(orderRequest))).thenReturn(orderDto);

        //then
        mockMvc.perform(post(orderSingleBookUri).with(csrf())
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(orderRequest)))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andExpect(content().string(equalTo(orderConfirm)));
    }

    //THIS TEST PASSES
    @Test
    @WithMockUser(roles = "USER")
    void givenUSERIsLoggedIn_whenOrderingBasket_thenReturnOrderNumberAndStatus201() throws Exception {
        //given
        String username = "username@gmail.com";
        OrderDto orderDto = OrderDtoFactory.newOrderDto().build();
        OrderResponse orderResp = OrderResponse.builder()
                .isbn(1234567890L)
                .id(1L)
                .build();
        String expectedBody = "Your order #" + orderResp.id() + " has been successfully placed.";

        //when
        when(extractionService.extractUserNameFromJwt(any(HttpServletRequest.class))).thenReturn(username);
        when(orderService.orderBasket(username)).thenReturn(orderDto);

        //then
        mockMvc.perform(post(orderBasketUri).with(csrf()))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andExpect(content().string(equalTo(expectedBody)));
    }
 

Stacktrace of failed test
2024-04-22T20:45:52.821+02:00  INFO 49724 --- [           main] c.s.H.controller.OrderControllerTest     : Started OrderControllerTest in 3.576 seconds (process running for 4.979)
2024-04-22T20:45:52.993+02:00 DEBUG 49724 --- [           main] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store anonymous SecurityContext
2024-04-22T20:45:53.017+02:00 DEBUG 49724 --- [           main] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /api/bookstore/book/12345/order
2024-04-22T20:45:53.036+02:00 DEBUG 49724 --- [           main] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using And [Not [RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]], MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@351e89fc, matchingMediaTypes=[application/xhtml+xml, image/*, text/html, text/plain], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]]
2024-04-22T20:45:53.037+02:00 DEBUG 49724 --- [           main] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using Or [RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest], And [Not [MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@351e89fc, matchingMediaTypes=[text/html], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[]]], MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@351e89fc, matchingMediaTypes=[application/atom+xml, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, application/json, application/octet-stream, application/xml, multipart/form-data, text/xml], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]], MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@351e89fc, matchingMediaTypes=[*/*], useEquals=true, ignoredMediaTypes=[]]]
2024-04-22T20:45:53.037+02:00 DEBUG 49724 --- [           main] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Match found! Executing org.springframework.security.web.authentication.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint@592cb470
2024-04-22T20:45:53.037+02:00 DEBUG 49724 --- [           main] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]
2024-04-22T20:45:53.037+02:00 DEBUG 49724 --- [           main] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : No match found. Using default entry point org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint@60e67c06

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction to fix this issue.
